# Struct changes after encode/decode

Tags: json, go, struct

The problem I'm currently having is after saving a struct to a json file and then opening the struct from the json file, somehow the properties of the struct have changed slightly.

In the struct N, sometimes A and B can point to the same J. However, after encoding then decoding they point to different Js of the value.

before encoding this returns true (expected). After decoding it, it returns false (not expected)

```
fmt.Println("is same pointer", n.A[0] == n.B[0])
```

Is this supposed to happen? Is there a way around this. Thanks.

```
type N struct {
        A       []*J
        B  []*J
        C []*J
    }

func (n *N) Save(name string) {
    name = "radacted.json"
    err := os.Remove(name)
    file, err := os.Create(name)
    defer file.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    bytes, err := json.Marshal(n)
    file.Write(bytes)
}

func Open(name string) *N {
    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("redacted.json")    
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("decode error:", err)
    }
    var n NeuralNetwork
    json.Unmarshal(bytes, &n)

    return &n
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's expected and documented behaviour

> Pointer values encode as the value pointed to.

You can assert values equality

```
*n.A[0] == *n.B[0]  //should stay
```

Answer (score 1):

> `fmt.Println("is same pointer", n.A[0] == n.B[0])`

you are comparing the address value here so it will not be the same. Let me give you an example 
suppose you have struct like this :

```
type Test struct {
    ValueA *int
    ValueB *int
}
```

and on your main function you add the same value but with different address in this case with different variable :

```
func main() {
    hello := 12
    hello2 := 12
    testObject := Test{ValueA: &hello, ValueB: &hello2}
    if *testObject.ValueA == *testObject.ValueB {
        fmt.Println("Equal Value")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Different  Value")
    }
}
```

Notice that the `*testObject.ValueA` and `*testObject.ValueB`is getting the exact value not the value address. If you are not using `*` the result would be different.

so as [uvelichitel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4374109/uvelichitel)  said you just need to use `*` when comparing your struct value.